# clicking "next page button", the page shows next page but the source codes of the page remains the same

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use selenium driver(chrome) to visit a commercial search engine. The problem is that when I click the "next page" button manually, it turns out the next page items,i.e. more search results show up. Surprisingly, when I check the source by right clicking the mouse "view page source" on the "next page",  the source codes are the same as the former page! That is to say, something hides the page source of the current(next page) page! When I right click the "save as" to save all information on my local disk, source page of the "next page" does show up! Why is that?

More worse, I use chromedriver to find the button "NextItem" and click it, but there is an "not clickable" error like this:

unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (452, 202). Other element would receive the click: ...

The part of my codes:

```
List<WebElement> nextItems = chrome.findElementsByClassName("nextItem");
nextItems.get(0).click();
String sourePage=chrome.getPageSource();
```

THEN CRASH....

Why I can manually click the button but it cannot be clicked by the chromedriver? 
 Need help!

Comment: How is that a selenium issue even if you can manually recreate the issue?!

Comment: If the page source of the chrome is not correct, how can I use the "Chrome.getPageSource()" function to get and further analyze the content?

Comment: All done. Thanks everyone! In fact, when I use the chrome.getPageSource() function to obtain the page source, the JavaScript codes one the page are executed and I do get the correct response. Another problem is: even ChromeDriver reports the some Exceptions like "StaleElementReferenceException", "ElementNotVisibleException",or"WebDriverException", the chromedrive does "click" the nextItem and page changes to the next correctly. What I   did is to ignore the Exceptions. Catch them and execute "continue".

Answer (score -1):

When executing tests using ChromeDriver, the "Element not clickable" error does happen if ChromeDriver attempts to "click" the element at an (x, y) location that is not actually clickable.  A workaround for this in C# is located at comment 27: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2766